# Object Detection using Intel Real sense

Tags: object, size, intel, detection, realsense

Is it possible to measure Object size using Intel realsense D435i depth camera .I have been using this device for a robotic usecase and wanted to measure the size change of an object .Basically I have a card holder in my table top and wanted to discover whether the card is present or not .

Answer (score 3):

Of course. One way to do that would be to use some object recognition algorithm to create a mask of the object. Depending on the complexity of the use case, you might need to use a deep learning solution like Mask-RCNN or DeepLab or you could probably use something simple like color thresholding. Once you have the mask, you can get the depth to those pixels from your depth image and measure the size.

If you have just this one object on a flat tabletop, another method you can use is background/floor removal. Using a method like [RANSAC](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/random_sample_consensus.php), detect and delete the tabletop surface. Ideally, you'll be left with only the object of interest to you. To get rid of any extraneous points left over in the point cloud, use an outlier filter. At this point, you can measure the size of the object, using some heuristic like maxX-minX, maxY-minY

Here's an example using the Python wrapper for PCL:
Original PointCloud:
[Original PointCloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qewwe.png)

1. (Optional) Cleaned with Statistical Outlier Filter (which I suggested in my last step).

```
    # Create a statistical filter object: 
    outlier_filter = cloud_filtered.make_statistical_outlier_filter()
    # Set the number of neighboring points to analyze for any given point
    outlier_filter.set_mean_k(3)
    # Set threshold scale factor
    x = 0.00001
    # Any point with a mean distance larger than global (mean distance+x*std_dev)
    # will be considered outlier
    outlier_filter.set_std_dev_mul_thresh(x)
    # Call the filter function
    cloud_filtered = outlier_filter.filter()
```

[Point CLoud with Outliers Removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAEvr.png)

2. (Optional) Pass-Through Filter:
   If the position of object of interest and table is known, you could remove extra points from the sides and above/below using a pass-through filter.

```
    # Create a PassThrough filter object.
    passthrough = cloud_filtered.make_passthrough_filter()
    # Assign axis and range to the passthrough filter object.
    filter_axis = 'z'
    passthrough.set_filter_field_name(filter_axis)
    axis_min = 0.6095
    axis_max = 1.1
    passthrough.set_filter_limits(axis_min, axis_max)
    # Use the filter function to obtain the resultant point cloud. 
    cloud_filtered = passthrough.filter()
```

[Point cloud decimated with Pass-Through Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lj3fG.png)

3. Apply RANSAC
   Detect the table surface by modelling it as a plane in the RANSAC algorithm and extract its corresponding points:

```
    # Create the segmentation object
    seg = cloud_filtered.make_segmenter()
    # Set the model you wish to fit 
    seg.set_model_type(pcl.SACMODEL_PLANE)
    seg.set_method_type(pcl.SAC_RANSAC)
    # Max distance for a point to be considered fitting the model
    # Experiment with different values for max_distance 
    # for segmenting the table
    max_distance = 0.006
    seg.set_distance_threshold(max_distance)
    # Call the segment function to obtain set of inlier indices and model coefficients
    inliers, coefficients = seg.segment()
    # Extract inliers (Table)
    extracted_table   = cloud_filtered.extract(inliers, negative=False)
    # Extract outliers (Tabletop Objects)
    extracted_objects = cloud_filtered.extract(inliers, negative=True)
```

[Table extracted via RANSAC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlV6j.png)

The left over points will be those of your object(s) of interest:
[Rest of the objects after removing table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eD7Qt.png)

Images are taken from Udacity's project as shown in this [post](https://github.com/mkhuthir/RoboND-Perception-Project).